# drawing hierarchical tree with orthogonal lines ( HV-Drawing – Binary Tree)

Tags: tree, lines, hierarchical, orthogonal

I need to work on drawing a hierarchical tree structure (HV-Drawing – Binary Tree) with orthogonal lines(straight rectangular connecting lines) between root and children ( like the following:
http://lab.kapit.fr/display/visualizationlayouts/Hierarchical+Tree+layout
).
I want to know if there are any open source examples of the algorithm of drawing trees like that so that I can implement the same algorithm in actionscript.
Thanks
Palash

Answer (score 0):

I did a C# version and put the code up on CodeProject.  It's at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/LayeredTreeDraw.aspx

There's a generic part which gives the positions of all the nodes and a WPF specific implementation which actually draws everything using either straight lines or the orthogonal lines you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **Python 3** realization: [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/VeLKerr/hv-embedding) (this is internal project, GitLab registration required).

The program consists of only one file, so the installation is very simple (clone the repository and run `hv-drawing.py` with necessary arguments).
Also the repository contents some examples of graphs for drawing.

The code is well-commented, so you can learn the algorithm on its realization.