# How can you print out a tree in a nicely formatted way?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, tree

What is the easiest way to print out a tree in it's tree-structure?  Such as...

```
                  some root
              /     |         \
          child1   child2     child 3
           /
      anotherchild               / \
                             yup     another
```

Even formatting it by hand is hard.  How can you make a program print a tree this way?

Comment: You should change the language-agnostic tag, since there are languages/environments where this is natively implemented.

Answer (score 6):

Unless there is some nice graphical library that you can use, you will have a lot of trouble representing a hierarchy in the way that you describe.

Assuming you want to print it to the Console, or a file, you will have to contend with pre-calculating the lengths of all of the data elements in the entire tree in order to line them up correctly. And how do you handle things like line-wrap?

A much better way is to represent the tree vertically, using indentation to show a child element.

```
Root
    - Child1
        - Grandchild1
        - Grandchild2
    - Child2
        - Grandchild3
        - Grandchild4
```

This is much simpler to code, and more tolerant of things like linewrap - as there is only ever one element on a line. This is how a folder-browser or xml document might display its hierarchical data.

To do it this way, you do a depth-first traversal and before the recursive step you print out the node:

```
public void PrintNode(TreeNode node)
{
    PrintNode(node, 0);
}

private void PrintNode(TreeNode node, int indentation)
{
    // Print the value to the console/file/whatever
    // This prefixes the value with the necessary amount of indentation
    Print(node.Value, indentation);

    // Recursively call the child nodes.
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in node.Children)
    {
        PrintNode(childNode, indentation + 1); // Increment the indentation counter.
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Surely you would pass indentation depth as a second argument to `PrintNode` (defaulting to 0 for client calls, and adding a level in the recursive call)? Then you wouldn't have to decrement it manually.

Comment: This isn't useful for printing a tree in the requested format.

Comment: @Zecc - That's what I meant by the last sentence (after my example). I was trying to write it in a language-agnostic way without specifying how indentation or printing was actually done. I'd actually usually have a public call that calls a private override with the 0 to hide that from the consumer.

Comment: @Paul Creasey - you got me - it's a lot easier to represent a tree with rows than horizontally using columns. The length of the data element you were printing could cause all kinds of misalignment. You also run into issues with column limits on the console. I think the answer is still useful. I wouldn't even entertain trying to print it out the way the question specifies it.

Comment: @Zecc - Ok, I've added your version. Now I am looking at it, I think my original simplification was unnecessary and that the latter method is clear enough. :-)

Comment: The major problem is that doing it vertically is exactly NOT what most people mean when they say "family tree". They want the ur-ancestor[s] in the middle at the top, and everyone else spread down and sideways from there. With multiple spouses, marriage of cousins, spousal trees, families with 20 children where the oldest got married and had offspring before the youngest was born, etc etc. Family trees are *messy* and they are not "trees" in the nice clean sense that computer scientists understand the word. Formatting them is *hard*.

Answer (score 5):

The following answer is in java, but it is so simple that it can easily be transcribed to other languages:

```
public interface Function1<R, T1>
{
    R invoke( T1 argument1 );
}

public interface Procedure1<T1>
{
    void invoke( T1 argument1 );
}

public static <T> void dump( T node, Function1<List<T>,T> breeder,
       Function1<String,T> stringizer, Procedure1<String> emitter )
{
    emitter.invoke( stringizer.invoke( node ) );
    dumpRecursive( node, "", breeder, stringizer, emitter );
}

private static final String[][] PREFIXES = { { " ├─ ", " │  " }, { " └─ ", "    " } };

private static <T> void dumpRecursive( T node, String parentPrefix,
        Function1<List<T>,T> breeder, Function1<String,T> stringizer,
        Procedure1<String> emitter )
{
    for( Iterator<T> iterator = breeder.invoke( node ).iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    {
        T childNode = iterator.next();
        String[] prefixes = PREFIXES[iterator.hasNext()? 0 : 1];
        emitter.invoke( parentPrefix + prefixes[0] + stringizer.invoke( childNode ) );
        dumpRecursive( childNode, parentPrefix + prefixes[1], breeder, stringizer, emitter );
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Automobile
 ├─ Passenger Vehicle
 │   ├─ Light Passenger Vehicle
 │   │   ├─ Two Wheeled
 │   │   │   ├─ Moped
 │   │   │   ├─ Scooter
 │   │   │   └─ Motorcycle
 │   │   ├─ Three Wheeled
 │   │   └─ Four Wheeled
 │   │       ├─ Car
 │   │       ├─ Station Wagon
 │   │       ├─ Pick-up Truck
 │   │       └─ Sports Utility Vehicle
 │   └─ Heavy Passenger Vehicle
 │       ├─ Bus
 │       │   ├─ Single-Deck Bus
 │       │   │   ├─ Mini Bus
 │       │   │   └─ Big Bus
 │       │   └─ Double-Deck Bus
 │       └─ Coach
 │           ├─ Deluxe
 │           └─ Air-Conditioned
 └─ Goods Vehicle
     ├─ Light Goods Vehicle
     │   ├─ Delivery Van
     │   ├─ Light Truck
     │   └─ Tempo
     │       ├─ Three Wheeler Tempo
     │       └─ Four Wheeler Tempo
     └─ Heavy Goods Vehicle
         ├─ Truck
         └─ Tractor Trailer
```

...if you invoke it using the following sample program:

```
final class Scratch
{
    static class Node
    {
        String name;
        List<Node> children;

        Node( String name, Node... children )
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.children = Arrays.asList( children );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Node tree = new Node( "Automobile",
                new Node( "Passenger Vehicle",
                        new Node( "Light Passenger Vehicle",
                                new Node( "Two Wheeled",
                                        new Node( "Moped" ),
                                        new Node( "Scooter" ),
                                        new Node( "Motorcycle" ) ),
                                new Node( "Three Wheeled" ),
                                new Node( "Four Wheeled",
                                        new Node( "Car" ),
                                        new Node( "Station Wagon" ),
                                        new Node( "Pick-up Truck" ),
                                        new Node( "Sports Utility Vehicle" ) ) ),
                        new Node( "Heavy Passenger Vehicle",
                                new Node( "Bus",
                                        new Node( "Single-Deck Bus",
                                                new Node( "Mini Bus" ),
                                                new Node( "Big Bus" ) ),
                                        new Node( "Double-Deck Bus" ) ),
                                new Node( "Coach",
                                        new Node( "Deluxe" ),
                                        new Node( "Air-Conditioned" ) ) ) ),
                new Node( "Goods Vehicle",
                        new Node( "Light Goods Vehicle",
                                new Node( "Delivery Van" ),
                                new Node( "Light Truck" ),
                                new Node( "Tempo",
                                        new Node( "Three Wheeler Tempo" ),
                                        new Node( "Four Wheeler Tempo" ) ) ),
                        new Node( "Heavy Goods Vehicle",
                                new Node( "Truck" ),
                                new Node( "Tractor Trailer" ) ) ) );
        dump( tree, n -> n.children, n -> n.name, s -> System.out.println( s ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I wrote a little library once called [text-tree](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/text-tree), which produces trees like that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try something like PHP's var_dump - if you try var_dump on a tree-like array, it will give you a fair representation of that tree, that is:

```
root {
    child1 {
        anotherchild
    }
    child2
    child3 {
        yup
        another
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't try it myself, [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) has a plain text [output format](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649027/how-do-i-print-out-a-tree-structure/1649223#1649223) to a similar question?
It prints a nice ASCII-art tree.

Or maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897575/drawing-hierarchical-tree-with-orthogonal-lines-hv-drawing-binary-tree) if you want to go fully graphical?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this last year writing a family tree application. Found a java tutorial online that helped but my Google-fu failed me today so I will have to simply explain it.

It is simply a recursive algorithm that adjusts position of parent node based on child nodes. In pseudocode it is something like this:

```
positionNode (node,x,y) {
    foreach (child in node.children) {
        positionNode(child,x,y+1)
        x ++
    }
    node.x = (x-1)/2
    node.y = y
}
```

I may not be remembering this correctly, you may need to tweak the code a bit to get it right.